# Moving to next ViewController after Facebook and Google sign in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-login, google-signin

I've successfully implemented Facebook and Google sign in Swift for my iOS app. I tried to check for sign-in and call `performSegue` so the user transitions to the next page if they've signed in. I put these conditionals in `viewWillAppear`, `viewdidAppear`, `viewdidLoad`, and `didSigninFor user`. The segue is still not working. Facebook and Google sign in present as a web page in a popover. Sign in is completed fine, but when the original viewController returns, it seems that none of my segue statements are never executed. What should I do? Code included below.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let token = AccessToken.current,
            !token.isExpired {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "facebook", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to implement delegates to get a callback from Google and then you can push new screen.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [example] showing what exactly is not working. "none of my segue statements are never executed" is not very helpful.

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Create a completion handler which will be called when your facebook login is successful something like this

```
func facebookLoginWithCompletionHandler(_ fromViewController: Any, onCompletion: @escaping FacebookLoginBlock) -> Void { ... }
```

this will return to your initial viewController form where you called the login function then in that completion block you call your segue

Comment: I am using the default Facebook login button. My `viewdidLoad` simply initializes the button.